# Unable to apply trigger on TextBlock within ListView/GridView

Tags: wpf, xaml

Unable apply the Style on GridViewDataTemplate field.
I just need to change the Forground of the TextBlock based on its contect.
If pull this textblock outside the list view it works perfectly. But inside the ListView it's not working.

Please let me how to fix this issue.

```
<ListView Margin="5,15,0,5" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="0"
                       ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Style>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataColumnStyle" DataType="GridViewColumn.CellTemplate">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="StatusColumnStyle" DataType="GridViewColumn.CellTemplate">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="Text"  Value="In Progress">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Complete">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Failed">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.Resources>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Activity}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataColumnStyle}" x:Name="ActivityColumn"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusColumnStyle}" Width="100" x:Name="StatusColumn"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you set the `DisplayMemberBinding` property, the `CellTemplate` property will be ignored; `DisplayMemberBinding` is fine if you're only looking to specify text, rather than a template.

So you'd need to change your code to something along these lines:

Altering the `Text` binding within the `DataTemplate':

```
Text="{Binding}" => Text="{Binding Activity}"
```

Removing the `DisplayMemberBinding` from the `ListView`:

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Activity}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataColumnStyle}" x:Name="ActivityColumn"/> => <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataColumnStyle}" x:Name="ActivityColumn"/>
```

Roughly:

```
 <!-- Your Code -->

<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataColumnStyle}" x:Name="ActivityColumn"/>
    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusColumnStyle}" Width="100" x:Name="StatusColumn"/>
</GridView>

 <!-- Your Code -->
```

If you have a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) info for `DisplayMemberInfo` (also CellTemplate / CellTemplateSelector), you can see that there is an order of precedence:

> The following properties are all used to define the content and style
>   of a column cell, and are listed here in their order of precedence,
>   from highest to lowest:
>
> ```
> DisplayMemberBinding
>
> CellTemplate
>
> CellTemplateSelector
> ```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I never thought about it. It solved my problem.